# A Cubic Equation

Tags: calculus, polynomials, quadratics, cubics

$2x^3+ax^2+bx+4=0$, $(a,b \in R^+)$ has three real roots. Then :

A. $a\geqslant 4.2^{\frac 1 3}$

B. $a\geqslant 1.2^{\frac 1 3}$

C. $a\geqslant 6.2^{\frac 1 3}$

D. $a\geqslant 2.2^{\frac 1 3}$

The only way I know how to do this is to find roots of its derivative($x_1,x_2$) and check opposite signs of $f(x_1),f(x_2)$ or one of them being $0$(Repeated roots).

But that would be too messy and ugly. Finding roots and putting them back... Also I think it would involve b. Any suggestions?

Comment: @Sabyasachi where is your answer?

Comment: It doesn't involve $b$, because you are looking for a condition that merely describes $a$. For example, if you ask "If $x^2+y^2 = 1$, then what can we say about $x$? The answer will be $-1 \leq x \leq 1$. Of course, we could make the answer conditional on $y$ too.

Comment: @CalvinLin $AM \geqslant GM$ should be fine?

Comment: I was typing up an answer yesterday when you deleted the question. The idea is to use the first derivative, and at those points one value must be positive and the other value must be negative.

Comment: @CalvinLin I fear that will be very messy. Sorry for deleting the question... was experimenting with options when the electricity went out... I mean using AM GM formula as we know sum and product of roots... but that yields C with sign of inequality reversed

Comment: That won't work because at least one of the roots is negative. The answer is C, which arises from $ 2 ( x + \sqrt[3]{2} ) ^3$.

Comment: @CalvinLin So, we really have to differentiate, find the roots and check for opposite signs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $2x^3+ax^2+bx+4$ with $a,b\gt0$ has three real roots, then all three must be negative, since the polynomial is clearly positive when $x\ge0$, so we can write

$$x^3+{a\over2}x^2+{b\over2}x+2=(x+r)(x+s)(x+t)$$

with $r,s,t\gt0$.  Expanding out the right hand side and equating coefficients allows us to apply the arithmetic-geometric mean inequality to conclude

$${a\over6}={r+s+t\over3}\ge\sqrt[3]{rst}=\sqrt[3]2$$